# Show that $A^k$ has eigenvalues $\lambda^k$ and eigenvectors $v$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda$ and
>   eigenvectors $v$. Show that $A^k$ has eigenvalues $\lambda^k$ and
>   eigenvectors $v$.

There are two ways I tried to prove this but I am not sure if either of them is accurate or complete.

1. If $Ax=\lambda x$ then multiplying by $A$ from the left yields

$$AAx=A \lambda x \iff A^2x=\lambda Ax \iff A^2x=\lambda (\lambda x)\iff A^2x=\lambda^2x$$

In fact, for every $A$ thats multiplied to both sides, the right side "gains" a factor $\lambda$ (since $Ax$ can be substituted by $\lambda x$) while the eigenvectors remain the same. It follows that multiplying both sides by $A^{k-1}$ yields:

$$A^{k-1}Ax=A^{k-1}\lambda x \iff A^kx=\lambda (\lambda^{k-1}x)\iff A^kx=\lambda^kx$$

2. This is a proof that I partly got from Gilbert Strang's Lin. Algebra lecture.

Suppose $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. Let $S$ be the matrix that has the eigenvectors of $A$ as its columns. Then,

$$AS=A\begin{bmatrix}x_1…x_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1x_1...\lambda_nx_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1...x_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&.&0\\0&\lambda_2&.&0\\.&.&.&.\\0&0&.& \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&.&0\\0&\lambda_2&.&0\\.&.&.&.\\0&0&.& \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$ then $AS=S\Lambda$

Multiplying by $S^{-1}$ from the right:

$$\implies S^{-1}AS=\Lambda \space \space \text{or} \space \space A=S \Lambda S^{-1}$$

$$\implies A^k=(S \Lambda S^{-1})^k=S \Lambda^kS^{-1}$$

It follows that $A^k$ has eigenvalues $\lambda^k$ and eigenvectors $x$.

I am not sure if either of them are correct. For the second one, I suspect that I need to guarantee that $S^{-1}$ exists or that $S$ is invertible but I am not sure how to do that. Also, how can I be sure that there are $n$ linearly indep. eigenvectors and not $n-1$ for example? Are there any problems with the first one?

Comment: The first one is indeed correct.

Comment: They are both correct. The first is more direct, and can be made more rigorous (than it is now) by proving it by induction. Strang is probably trying to give you an argument using diagonalization, just to get you used to the concept, but his proof is limited to diagonalizable matrices, while the induction proof works if you only know some of the eigenvalues or eigenvectors.

Comment: I find your proof more simple, more direct, more general and more obvious, thus much better.

Comment: An invertible choice of $S$ exists if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The proof is actually sort of showing this - it builds a specific $S$.

Comment: @SuH we know that $S$ is invertible because its columns are linearly independent. This is an assumption Strang makes before the second proof.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You can make the second proof work if you use the Jordan Normal form.