# What are the Eigenvalues of $A^2?$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $A^2$ has an eigenvalue $a^2.$ But what about the multiplicities? I mean is it possible to have $1,1,2$ as the eigenvalues of a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ and $1,4,8$ as the eigenvalues of $A^2?$

Comment: Hint: Think determinants.

Comment: I got your point. while in that we can modify this question for a 4×4 matrix with A has eigen value 1,1,1,2 . Then can it be possible to have 1,4,3,1/3. this time (det A)^2=(det A^2) satisfied.

Answer (score 9):

Let

$$P(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)=(\lambda-\lambda_1)\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_n)$$

be the characteristic polynomial for $A$ Then

$$\begin{align}
\det(\lambda I+A)&=(-1)^n\det(-\lambda I-A)\\
&=(-1)^nP(-\lambda)\\
&=(-1)^n(-\lambda-\lambda_1)\cdots(-\lambda-\lambda_n)\\
&=(\lambda+\lambda_1)\cdots(\lambda+\lambda_n)
\end{align}$$

Now if $Q(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A^2)$ is the characteristic polynomial for $A^2$, then

$$\begin{align}
Q(\lambda^2)
&=\det(\lambda^2I-A^2)\\
&=\det(\lambda I-A)\det(\lambda I+A)\\
&=(\lambda-\lambda_1)\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_n)(\lambda+\lambda_1)\cdots(\lambda+\lambda_n)\\
&=(\lambda^2-\lambda_1^2)\cdots(\lambda^2-\lambda_n^2)
\end{align}$$

which gives us an identity for the polynomial $Q$. It follows that $Q(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_1^2)\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_n^2)$. Thus the eigenvalues of $A^2$ cannot be anything other than the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a square matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda$, we can apply induction on the size of the matrix to show that the eigenvalues of $A^{k}$ are $\lambda^{k}$ for any positive integer $k$. Hence, the eigenvalues of $A^{2}$ are exactly $\lambda^{2}$ (the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$). See here: [Show that $A^k$ has eigenvalues $\lambda^k$ and eigenvectors $v$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346901/show-that-ak-has-eigenvalues-lambdak-and-eigenvectors-v)

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $k$, then $a^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ with multiplicity at least $k$. So, the answer is negative: if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ and its multiplicity as at least $2$, then $4$ and $8$ can't be eigenvalues too.

Comment: I am not getting about the Multiplicities. How can you say that a^2 has at least multiplicity k?

Comment: If $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are linearly independent vectors and each of them is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $a$, then they are also eigenvectors of $A^2$ with eigenvalue $a^2$.

Comment: And all the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are squares of eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: ok. my confusions are clear now. thank you very much @jose carlos santos.

Comment: @jose carlos santos I am sorry but I couldn't get my answer though. If 'a' has multiplicities 4 (say) then it need not have four Linealy independent eigen vectors  .So we can't say that a^2 has Multiplicities at least 4. Can you please Explicitly give the answer?

Comment: But if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ with multiplicity $2$ then, since $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix, there is no room for the eigenvalues $4$ **and** $8$.

Comment: ok. Just leave that previous question. I just want to know that if a is an eigen value of A with k times repeatation then can we say that a^2 is an eigen value of A^2 with k times repeatation. if so then please give an explicit proof.

Comment: No, that is not true in general. All you can say is that the multiplicity of $a^2$ is *at least* $k$.

Comment: please help me to figure out how can we say that a^2 has multiplicities at least k?

Comment: I have already provided an answer to that question in my first comment.